# How to go to from my initial page to a new html page with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create on my website everytime someone press on of those  item 1 ,2,3,4,5, or 6 then will seemed a message "You choose me!!!" and then  (with a button maybe - I don't know ) will linked  to a new html page.Example if item 1 as we name it HOME . If someone goes to HOME then a message will seemed(You choose me) and then will go to a new html page named HOME.I tryed to do that but I stucked. Until the code it worked is this.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-7">
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<script>
function MyFun(event){
    t = event.target ;
    if(t.tagName=='LI'){
        t.innerHTML="You choose me!!!"
    }


}

</script>


</head>


<body>

    <ul onclick="MyFun(event)">
        <li> item 1</li>
        <li> item 2</li>
        <li> item 3</li>
        <li> item 4</li>
        <li> item 5</li>
        <li> item 6</li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll("li"),
  len = items.length,
  alreadyAdded = [],
  prevAdded = -1;

for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName == "LI" && alreadyAdded[i] !== 1) {
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = "#your-path-" + (i + 1);
      a.innerHTML = "You choose me! I'm the " + (i + 1) + " link";
      this.appendChild(a);

      if (prevAdded !== -1) {
        items[prevAdded].removeChild(items[prevAdded].lastChild);
        alreadyAdded[prevAdded] = -1;
      }
      alreadyAdded[i] = 1;
      prevAdded = i;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 12px;
}

a {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0 0.25rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin: 0 0.25rem;
  border-radius:3px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-7">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>

  <ul id="items">
    <li> item 1</li>
    <li> item 2</li>
    <li> item 3</li>
    <li> item 4</li>
    <li> item 5</li>
    <li> item 6</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the OP was using event delegation, and this removes it. Not cool!!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer to your question, is to set the variable `location.href` to your desired HTML file. If you want to display your message ("You chose me"), then wait 1 second before redirecting, use setTimeout().

```
function MyFun(event){
    t = event.target ;
    if(t.tagName=='LI'){
        t.innerHTML="You choose me!!!"

        setTimeout(()=>{
           location.href = //the HTML path.
        }, 1000);
    }


}
```

Remember, you have to store your HTML path somewhere, and you may want to store it in a data-XXX attribute in each `<li>`, then getting it in your `onclick` function handler. See custom attributes.

This is very simplistic, however, and you may want to eventually consider using a framework with routing!

Comment: it must be 6 new html ,not only one.Only one will open when I press example item1 . You get it? with other words 6 new html are ,not 1